# WinAPI union punning of PODs to fundamental types: Implementation dependent or standard compliant?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, language-lawyer, type-punning

When dealing with the Windows API, one often stumbles across structs when large numbers are needed. MSDN documentation encourages to use union punning on those structs to convert them to fundamental types.
Are those conversions standard compliant or is MSDN suggesting techniques that could cause undefined behaviour?

For example, when dealing with the FILETIME struct and arithmetics need to be done, [the MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms724284%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) suggests:

> It is not recommended that you add and subtract values from the FILETIME structure to obtain relative times. Instead, you should copy the low- and high-order parts of the file time to a ULARGE_INTEGER structure, perform 64-bit arithmetic on the QuadPart member, and copy the LowPart and HighPart members into the FILETIME structure.

ULARGE_INTEGER is declared

```
typedef union _ULARGE_INTEGER {
  struct {
    DWORD LowPart;
    DWORD HighPart;
  };
  struct {
    DWORD LowPart;
    DWORD HighPart;
  } u;
  ULONGLONG QuadPart;
} ULARGE_INTEGER, *PULARGE_INTEGER;
```

So what the documentation suggests, e.g. for calculating time spans, is something like this:

```
FILETIME filetime[2];
ULARGE_INTEGER large[2];
// ...
large[0].LowPart  = filetime[0].dwLowDateTime;
large[0].HighPart = filetime[0].dwHighDateTime;
large[1].LowPart  = filetime[1].dwLowDateTime;
large[1].HighPart = filetime[1].dwHighDateTime;

auto diff = large[1].QuadPart - large[0].QuadPart;
```

The Standard has this infamous section that is always brought up in similar questions (quoting N3337):

> In a union, at most one of the non-static data members can be active at any time, that is, the value of at most one of the non-static data members can be stored in a union at any time. [ Note: One special guarantee is made in order to simplify the use of unions: If a standard-layout union contains several standard-layout structs that share a common initial sequence (9.2), and if an object of this standard-layout union type contains one of the standard-layout structs, it is permitted to inspect the common initial sequence of any of standard-layout struct members; see 9.2. — end note ]

9.2 specifically refers to structs then.

Since ULONGLONG resolves to __int64 or double, the ULARGE_INTEGER union contains two structs and one fundamental type. As I am reading it, the special guarantee from the quote does not apply, because setting HighPart and LowPart and subsequentially reading QuadPart would be setting two members of a struct and then reading a fundamental type. The quote requires all contained entities that can be read / written interchangeably to be **structs**.

So does MSDN advise techniques that go against the standard in this special case or am I getting it wrong?

Comment: MSDN can advice on techniques that work for their compiler. Obviously, things from the Windows.h header is used internally in Windows, and just have to work with that compiler. Standards-wise it is just a mess.

Comment: @BoPersson: The Windows API is exposed as a C interface. Type punning through unions is officially legal since C99 (and has been implementation defined up until C89). The true mess is not the Windows API. The true wtf is, that type punning through unions isn't legal in C++.

Comment: @IInspectable: Oh, you are right. I never thought about it twice when using a C interface in my C++ compilation units, so it completely slipped me here.

Comment: @IInspectable: Type punning through unions is less well defined under gcc/clang's interpretation of C99 than under C89.  In C89, the effects of type punning were Implementation-Defined, which implied that an implementation where it would do something other than bitwise reinterpretation--*even when taking the addresses of union objects and using the resulting pointers*--would need to document that fact.  Under the gcc/clang interpretation of c99, the act of taking the address of a union member does not make the resulting pointer usable for the purpose of writing that member...

Comment: ...even if all writes to the member via that pointer are performed before the union lvalue is used in any way (such as taking the address of another member).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going strictly by the C++ standard, the behaviour is indeed Undefined (as you reason). However, bear in mind that was is not defined by the standard can still be defined by the implementation. It wouldn't surprise me if MSDN was written with the MSVC compiler in mind, which can very well provide defined behaviour in such case. I believe GCC declares union-based type punning to be defined as well.

Comment: I am marking this as the answer, because it is technically correct. MSDN encourages to use implementation defined features of MSVC. For the probable reason see @BoPerssons comment under the question: It is originally a C Interface.

Comment: Sorry, I mean @IInspectable's comment.